# Pass option text instead of option value to a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will pass value for multiple fields to a text field. There is a problem, select options, its value are 0 and 1, my question is how to make sure that it pass option text instead of 0 and 1? That mean pass MYR instead of 0 and SGD instead of 1?

http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/64/

HTML:

```
<select id="Salary_para1">
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="0" selected>MYR</option>
  <option value="1" >SGD</option>
</select>
<input id="Salary_value" type="text"/>
+ <input type="checkbox" id="Salary_para2" name="Salary_para2" value=" + Allowance"  />Allowance<br/>
<input type="text" id="targetTextField" name="targetTextField" size="31" tabindex="0" maxlength="99" value="">
```

CODE:

```
$(function() {
  setTarget();
  $("#Salary_para1,#Salary_para2").change(setTarget);
  $("#Salary_value").keyup(setTarget);

  function setTarget() {
    var tmp = $("#Salary_para1").val();
    tmp += $("#Salary_value").val();
    tmp += $("#Salary_para2:checked").val() || '';
    $('#targetTextField').val(tmp);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not just use MYR and SGD as the values in the original HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the text and not the value of whatever is selected in the dropdown, you'd have to target the selected option and get the text from that element :

```
var tmp = $("option:selected", "#Salary_para1").text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/65/)

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you can't change the markup, so that option's value is equal to option's text.
For example:

```
<option value="MYR" selected>MYR</option>
```

If you can't change the markup, then you can get the option's text using [jQuery text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

```
var tmp = $("#Salary_para1 option:selected").text();
```

Comment: I don't think this'd work.  That "id" is for the `<select>` element, not the `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this -

```
var tmp = $('option:selected', '#Salary_para1').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getelementById('id').value.select=[position]